step-fixed algorithm to minimize f, which step to ensure convergence?
If we want to apply the fixed-step gradient algorithm to the minimization of $f(x) = \frac{1}{2}(Ax, x)$ where $A$ is a symmetric 2x2 matrix with eigenvalues $\lambda_1 > \lambda_2 > 0$, for which step $p$ can we ensure convergence?

What is $p$ here? You need to learn to write better questions in which you explain what each symbol is.

Also, how do you define "convergence" here? Strictly speaking, convergence means that you are getting closer and closer to a solution. That's a qualitative property, not one where you can say "now I've achieved it".

@WolfgangBangerth p is the step size, convergence is in its technical sense, the we re getting closer to the solution approximatively.

But the step size of what? Is it an absolute length, or is it a multiple of the negative gradient? These things matter, but we really can't know unless you tell us.

But if it's an absolute step length, then clearly the algorithm can only converge if you use different step lengths for different iterations -- specifically, you need a sequence of step lengths that decreases to zero.

Fixed step gradient descent $x^{k+1} = x^k - \alpha \nabla f(x^k)$ for $f(x) = \frac{1}{2}x^TAx - x^Tb + c$ results in the Richardson iteration $x^{k+1} = x^k + \alpha (b-Ax^k)$. The iteration can be written as $x^{k+1} = Gx^k + \alpha b$ with iteration matrix $G=(I-\alpha A)$. Let $x^*$ be the solution, then
\begin{align}
e^{k+1} &= x^{k+1} - x^* 
\\ &= Gx^k + \alpha b - x^* 
\\ &= Gx^k + \alpha Ax^* - x^*  
\\ &= Gx^k - Gx^*
\\ &= Ge^k.
\end{align}
So $\|e^{k+1}\| = \|G^{k+1}e^0\| \leq \|G\|^{k+1} \|e^0\|$. A sufficient condition for the latter to go to zero as the iterations increase is $\|G\|<1$. Specifically for the $2$-norm you would need that $|1-\alpha \lambda_i|<1$, i.e., if $A$ is positive-definite: $0<\alpha<\frac{2}{\lambda_{\max}}$. If $A$ is semi-definite or indefinite then you cannot ensure $\|G\|_2<1$ for any $\alpha$. However, it is actually fine if $A$ is semi-definite and the system is consistent, as then there are infinitely many solutions each a shifted version of the others with a shift in the kernel of $A$. So even if you do not decrease the error along the kernel to some specific $x^*$, you would decrease it to some other solution $y^*$. Thus the only issue arises when $A$ is indefinite.
If $A$ is indefinite, but $e^0$ is in the eigenspaces of the non-negative eigenvalues (or only in the eigenspaces of the non-positive ones), then the process is still convergent since the iteration remains in these subspaces.

Thanks a lot! Though I did a typo, I meant $\lambda_1 > \lambda_2 > 0$

@V_head $\lambda_{\max}$ refers to the largest eigenvalue in my answer, so $\lambda_1$ for you. Note also that GD with the optimal step size is better, and conjugate gradients is even better, and for small positive definite matrices use Cholesky. For your problem $x^*=0$ is the minimizer though, so not very interesting.

I see, someone else suggested to me that it can be $0 < p < \frac{2 \lambda_1}{\lambda_2^2}$
another colleague suggested $0 < p < \frac{2 \lambda_1^2}{\lambda_2}$ !

I added another question on the same algorithm https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/questions/44396/step-fixed-algorithm-first-iterates

@V_head You can ask whoever suggested these step size constraints how they derived them.
