step-fixed algorithm first iterates
let us have the fixed-step gradient algorithm, with $p = 2$ and we assume that for $X = (x, y)$,
$∇ f(X) = \begin{pmatrix}
x -1\\
y -2
\end{pmatrix}$
Let me assume we intialize with $X_0 = (0,0)$ what will be the first three iterates $X_1, X_2, X_3$? I am assuming it they would be $X_1 = (2,4), X_2 = (0,0), X_3 = (2,4)$, is this correct?

What is $\Delta f(x,y)$? And how did you conclude those would be the iterates?

haha, sorry I meant gradient! I followed some lecture notes I found online, just by mentally trying to follow with some computations, but I have no idea if that s correct, I am still learning about this fixed step gradient version.

As in other questions, what is $p$ in your description, and what is $s$ in your previous comment? We cannot look into your head, you will have to become better at explaining what it is you are asking.

@WolfgangBangerth I didn't leave any $s$ in any comment, where?

But you do: "but I have no idea if that s correct". I have no idea what "that s" is supposed to refer to.

that s just that's!

The resulting confusion simply reinforces my suggestion that you ought to put more work into how you write questions.

Gradient descent has the following iteration
\begin{equation}
X_{k+1} = X_k - \alpha_k \nabla f(X_k).
\end{equation}
Assuming that $X_0 = 0$, and $\nabla f(X) = \begin{bmatrix} x-1 \\ y - 2\end{bmatrix}$ the iterates are:
\begin{align}
X_1 &= \begin{bmatrix} 0 \\ 0 \end{bmatrix} - \alpha_0\begin{bmatrix} -1 \\ -2 \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} \alpha_0 \\ 2\alpha_0 \end{bmatrix}, \\
X_2 &= \begin{bmatrix} \alpha_0 \\ 2\alpha_0 \end{bmatrix} - \alpha_1\begin{bmatrix} \alpha_0-1 \\ 2\alpha_0-2\end{bmatrix} 
= \begin{bmatrix} \alpha_0-\alpha_1(\alpha_0-1) \\ 2(\alpha_0-\alpha_1(\alpha_0-1))\end{bmatrix}, \\
X_3 &= \begin{bmatrix} \alpha_0-\alpha_1(\alpha_0-1) \\ 2(\alpha_0-\alpha_1(\alpha_0-1)) \end{bmatrix} -\alpha_2\begin{bmatrix}1-\alpha_0 + \alpha_1(\alpha_0-1) \\  2(1-\alpha_0 + \alpha_1(\alpha_0-1))\end{bmatrix}.
\end{align}
I don't think this provides any insights though, I am not sure what the purpose is of looking at these iterates. Typically a computer computes those.
By the way, if the gradient is $\begin{bmatrix} x-1\\ y-2\end{bmatrix}$ then the function was
\begin{align}
f(x,y) &= \frac{1}{2}x^2 - x + \frac{1}{2}y^2 - y + c 
\\ &= \frac{1}{2}\begin{bmatrix} x & y \end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 1\end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} x \\ y \end{bmatrix} - \begin{bmatrix} x & y \end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ 2 \end{bmatrix} + c 
\\ &= \frac{1}{2}X^TAX - X^T B + c. 
\end{align}
Taking the gradient and setting it to zero in order to find the stationary points we get
\begin{equation}
\frac{1}{2}(A+A^T)X = B.
\end{equation}
If $A+A^T$ is non-singular then this has a unique solution $X = 2(A+A^T)^{-1}B$. Since $\frac{1}{2}(A+A^T) = I_2$ in your case you get $X = B = \begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ 2 \end{bmatrix}$. In general $A+A^T$ may be singular, then if $B$ is not in the span of $A+A^T$ there is no solution. If $A+A^T$ is singular and $B$ is in the span of $A+A^T$ then there are infinitely many solutions each a shifted variant of the others along the kernel of $A+A^T$. The gradient decent algorithm is meant to minimize the objective $f$, the latter has a minimum when $X^TAX\geq 0$ and $B$ is in the span of $A+A^T$. If $X^TAX\geq 0$ then $A+A^T$ is positive semi-definite, and a sufficient condition for the gradient descent algorithm to converge is $0<\alpha_k<\frac{2}{\frac{1}{2}\lambda_{\max}(A+A^T)}$. For a fixed step size the optimal choice is $\alpha = \frac{2}{\lambda_{\min} + \lambda_{\max}}$, where $\lambda_{\min}$ and $\lambda_{\max}$ are the respectively the minimum and maximum eigenvalues of $\frac{1}{2}(A+A^T)$, see the Wikipedia article on the convergence of the Richardson iteration.

Thanks, wait what is $α_1$?

@V_head I just allowed for different step sizes $\alpha_0, \alpha_1,\alpha_2$, you can make all of those equal if you wish, then it's fixed step size gradient descent. But the latter is not very efficient.

Yeah exactly, because mine is $α = 2$

So then: $X_1 = [2, 2], X_2 = [0, 0] ...$, interesting, thanks

@V_head Then you can check by plugging this in that the iteration will oscillate between $\begin{bmatrix} 0 \ 0 \end{bmatrix}$ and $\begin{bmatrix} 2 \ 2 \end{bmatrix}$. The step is simply too large, so it overjumps the solution $\begin{bmatrix} 1 \ 1 \end{bmatrix}$. Note that the sufficient condition for convergence was $0<\alpha_k<\frac{2}{\frac{1}{2}\lambda_{\max}(A+A^T)}$ which is your case reads $0<\alpha_k<2$, but you picked $\alpha_k = 2$, which is outside of this range. If you pick $1.999$ it should converge but slowly. $\alpha = \frac{\lambda_1+\lambda_2}{2}=1$ is much better here.

Perfect explanation, thank you very much

@V_head The $-2$ just makes $B = \begin{bmatrix} 1 \ 2 \end{bmatrix}$, and the iterates $X_1 = \begin{bmatrix} 2 \ 4 \end{bmatrix}$, $X_2 = \begin{bmatrix} 0 \ 0 \end{bmatrix}$, $X_3 = \begin{bmatrix} 2 \ 4 \end{bmatrix}$, and so on. It doesn't change the sufficient condition for convergence being $0<\alpha < 2$. I wrote $\alpha = \frac{\lamba_1 + \lambda_2}{2}$ as the optimal one - that's wrong, it should read $\alpha = \frac{2}{\lambda_{\min}+\lambda_{\max}}$. You can read more here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modified_Richardson_iteration#Convergence

Great, ok, I ll formulate another question to ask how formally to choose for an optimal-step rather than a fixed step which can be not helpful.

https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/questions/44399/optimal-gradient-algorithm-to-determine-best-%ce%b1-k
