optimal gradient algorithm to determine best $α_k$
Let's consider an optimal-step gradient algorithm and assume that:
$g(α) := f(X_k - α∇f(X_k)) = 2α^2-4α+17$, how can we determine the optimal $α_k$?
Here is my simple solution:
$g(α) = 2α^2-4α+17$
$g'(α) = 4α - 4$ and $g'(α) = 0 \iff α = 1$ for critical point, and $g''(α) = 4 > 0$, thus $α_k = 1$.
Is this the approach, as simple as it is?

Please don't spam this forum with homework questions. Please make an attempt yourself and explain the context and your own thoughts in the post

They are not homework, this is summer, I just started interesting stuff that is directly applicable in my ml work I just started. This question was based on the last answer to one of my questions, about a bad choice of a step size.

Well please add additional context and your own attempts to the post. Your current question is asking to minimize a quadratic. Perhaps give it a try

@whpowell96 I just did

It might be not homework, but you're asking similar questions and not even accepting the answers.

Setup
I will consider a more general objective function:
\begin{equation}
f(x) = \frac{1}{2}x^T\tilde{A}x - x^Tb + c, \quad A\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times n}.
\end{equation}
Note that if you transpose scalars they remain the same, so $x^T\tilde{A}x$ is equal to $(x^T\tilde{A}x)^T = x^T\tilde{A}^Tx$. Then we can use:
\begin{equation}
x^T\tilde{A}x = \frac{1}{2}x^T\tilde{A}x + \frac{1}{2}\overbrace{x^T\tilde{A}x}^{x^T\tilde{A}^Tx} = 
\frac{1}{2}x^T\tilde{A}x + \frac{1}{2}x^T\tilde{A}^Tx = 
\frac{1}{2}x^T(\tilde{A}+\tilde{A}^T)x.
\end{equation}
So even if $\tilde{A}$ is non-symmetric we can substitute the term $x^T\tilde{A}x$ with $\frac{1}{2}x^T(\tilde{A}+\tilde{A}^T)x$. For brevity denote $A = \frac{1}{2}(\tilde{A}+\tilde{A}^T)$, then we can rewrite the objective function as:
\begin{equation}
f(x) = \frac{1}{2}x^TAx - x^Tb + c,
\end{equation}
where now $A$ is symmetric. For the minimization problem
$$\min_{x\in\mathbb{R}^n}f(x) = \min_{x\in\mathbb{R}^n} \frac{1}{2}x^TAx - x^Tb + c$$
to have a solution we need that $A$ is positive semi-definite ($y^TAy\geq 0$ for any $y\in\mathbb{R}^n$) and $b \in \operatorname{span}(A)$. If $A$ is non-singular
(and thus positive definite) then the problem has a unique solution $x = A^{-1}b$,
otherwise there are infinitely many solutions satisfying $Ax=b$, and each of those
is offset from any other by an offset in the kernel of $A$. If $A$ is not positive semi-definite then I can make $f$ as small as I wish by walking along the eigenspace of a negative eigenvalue, so the minimum also doesn't exist (it is $-\infty$).

Optimal Step Size
Let $p\in\mathbb{R}^n$ be non-zero $p\ne 0$, and we are given a point $x\in\mathbb{R}^n$. We want to find the optimal step size $\alpha\in\mathbb{R}$
along $p$ starting at $x$ such that $y = x + \alpha p$ minimizes $f(y)$. Equivalently, we want to minimize the function of scalar argument $g(\alpha) = f(x+\alpha p)$:
\begin{equation}
\min_{\alpha\in\mathbb{R}} g(\alpha) = 
\min_{\alpha\in\mathbb{R}} f(x+\alpha p) = 
\min_{\alpha\in\mathbb{R}} \frac{1}{2}(x+\alpha p)^TA (x+\alpha p) - 
(x+\alpha p)^Tb + c.
\end{equation}
We can expand the latter as follows:
\begin{align}
g(\alpha) &= \frac{1}{2}(x+\alpha p)^TA (x+\alpha p) - 
(x+\alpha p)^Tb + c 
\\
&= \overbrace{\frac{1}{2}x^TAx - x^Tb + c}^{f(x)} + \frac{\alpha}{2} \overbrace{x^TAp}^{(x^TAp)^T} + 
\frac{\alpha}{2}  p^TA x + \frac{\alpha^2}{2}p^TAp - \alpha p^Tb 
\\
&= \frac{\alpha^2}{2} p^TAp + \alpha p^T\left(Ax-b\right) + f(x).
\end{align}
The above is a quadratic function in $\alpha$, its derivative is:
\begin{equation}
g'(\alpha) = \alpha p^TAp + p^T\left(Ax-b\right).
\end{equation}
The stationary points of $g$ satisfy $g'(\alpha) = 0$, and for $p^TAp>0$ those are minima since the second derivative is $g''(\alpha) = p^TAp>0$ then. Thus we can solve for $\alpha$:
\begin{equation}
 0 = g'(\alpha) = \alpha p^TAp - p^T(b-Ax) \implies \alpha = \frac{p^T(b-Ax)}{p^TAp}.
\end{equation}
In the above we have found the optimal step size as a function of $x$ and $p$. Do
note that the direction here didn't necessarily have to be the negated gradient
of $f$, it suffices that $p^TAp$ is non-zero. This is useful if
you use other iterative methods - e.g. for example conjugate gradients, where the
direction $p$ is not the negated gradient.
I should also mention that if you pick $p$ in the kernel of $A$ then
$g(\alpha) = -\alpha p^Tb + f(x)$. Since to have a solution $b$ should be in the
span of $A$ (i.e. should not have components in the kernel of $A$) it follows
$p^Tb = 0$, so $g(\alpha) = f(x)$, and you can't actually move, so the direction
$p$ should at least be chosen so that it is not fully in the kernel of $A$.

The Gradient of $f$
To find the gradient of $f$ we can take the directional derivative $\partial_v f(x)$ and use that $v^T\nabla f(x) = \partial_v f(x)$:
\begin{align}
\partial_v f(x) &:= \lim_{\epsilon\to 0} \frac{f(x+\epsilon v)-f(x)}{\epsilon}
\\
&= \lim_{\epsilon\to 0}\frac{\frac{1}{2}(x+\epsilon v)^TA(x+\epsilon v) - (x+\epsilon v)^Tb +c - f(x)}{\epsilon} \\
&= \lim_{\epsilon\to 0} \frac{\overbrace{\frac{1}{2}x^TAx - x^Tb+ c}^{f(x)}  + \frac{1}{2}\epsilon x^TAv + \frac{1}{2}\epsilon v^TAx + \frac{1}{2}\epsilon^2v^TAv - \epsilon v^Tb - f(x)}{\epsilon}
\\
&= \lim_{\epsilon\to 0} \frac{\frac{1}{2}\epsilon^2 v^TAv + \frac{1}{2}\epsilon (x^TAv)^T + \frac{1}{2}\epsilon v^TAx -\epsilon v^Tb}{\epsilon}
\\
&= \lim_{\epsilon\to 0} \frac{1}{2}\epsilon v^TAv + v^TAx - v^Tb
\\
&= v^TAx - v^Tb = v^T\overbrace{\left(Ax - b\right)}^{\nabla f(x)}.
\end{align}
The gradient could have also been derived by taking derivatives of the various components. In either case, such differentiation falls within the field of matrix calculus, you can find some identities on Wikipedia, as well as in the matrix cookbook.
We know that the stationary points of $f$ satisfy $\nabla f(x) = 0$:
\begin{equation}
\nabla f(x) = Ax - b = 0 \iff Ax = b.
\end{equation}
Moreover, we know that any such stationary point is a minimum since the Hessian
\begin{equation}
H(f)(x) = \frac{d}{dx}(\nabla f)(x) = \frac{d(Ax-b)}{dx} = A
\end{equation}
is positive semi-definite (remember we chose $A$ to be positive semi-definite). So the minima satisfy $Ax = b$.

Gradient Descent with optimal Step Size
Consider the iteration $x_{k+1} = x_k + \alpha_k p_k$, where $p_k$ is not in the kernel of $A$. Then we know the optimal step size for this iteration is:
\begin{equation}
\alpha^k = \frac{p_k^Tr_k}{p_k^TAp_k}, \quad r_k = b-Ax_k = -\nabla f(x_k).
\end{equation}
The vector $r_k$ is typically termed the residual since it is the difference between the right-hand side and the left-hand side of $Ax=b$ (i.e. residual = what is left over). We can now formulate an iterative process:

Pick some initial guess $x_0\in\mathbb{R}^n$
Compute $r_0 = b-Ax_0$, set $k=0$
While $\frac{\|r_k\|_2}{\|r_0\|_2}>\epsilon$ and $k< \textrm{max_iter}$ repeat:
Generate a direction $p_k$ not in the kernel of $A$
Compute $\alpha_k = \frac{p_k^Tr_k}{p_k^TAp_k}$
Compute the next iterate: $x_{k+1} = x_k + \alpha_k p_k$
Compute the new residual: $r_{k+1} = b-Ax_{k+1}$
Next iteration $k\gets k+1$

You may note that in the above we need two matrix-vector multiplications per iteration. This is actually not necessary as $r_{k+1} = b-Ax_{k+1} = b-A(x_k-\alpha_k p_k) = r_k - \alpha Ap_k$. With an extra vector $q_k = Ap_k$ we can
rewrite this with one matrix-vector multiplication per iteration:

Pick some initial guess $x_0\in\mathbb{R}^n$
Compute $r_0 = b-Ax_0$, set $k=0$
While $\frac{\|r_k\|_2}{\|r_0\|_2}>\epsilon$ and $k< \textrm{max_iter}$ repeat:
Generate a direction $p_k$ not in the kernel of $A$
Compute $q_k = Ap_k$
Compute $\alpha_k = \frac{p_k^Tr_k}{p_k^Tq_k}$
Compute the next iterate: $x_{k+1} = x_k + \alpha_k p_k$
Compute the new residual: $r_{k+1} = r_k-\alpha_k q_k$
Next iteration $k\gets k+1$

If you choose $p_k = -\nabla f(x_k) = r_k$ then you get gradient descent with an optimal step size per iteration for the given quadratic objective function $f$.
Note that gradient descent is not optimal for this problem, conjugate gradients would perform better.

That s what I was expecting, a sophisticated answer, though for many it's an overkill as I already showed it with a simple solution, but it's a great one, thanks!
